# Jetpack Compose Material 3 Error . Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have Two lines of error when i run the simple Jetpack Compose Material 3 Project

build.gradle(Project:)

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.0-beta02'
        core_ktx_version = '1.9.0-rc01'
        material3_version = 'material3:1.3.0-beta02'
        lifecycle_version =  '2.4.1'
        activity_compose_version = '1.5.1'
        nav_version = "2.5.2"
        hilt_version = "2.42"
        hilt_nav_fragment = "1.0.0"
        lottieVersion = "5.2.0"
        timber_version = "5.0.1"
        hilt_navigation_compose = "1.0.0"
        room_version = "2.3.0-beta02"
        kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module : )

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jetpackcompose.jp1"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:$material3_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$activity_compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.3.1"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-beta01'
    // hilt -android
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // To Integrate Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

    // To use additional extensions of navigation frameworks like hiltViewModel()
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:$hilt_nav_fragment"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hilt_navigation_compose"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
 }
```

settings.gradle:

```
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "jp1"
include ':app'
```

when i run the project i have an error of :

Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-beta02.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose compiler and the other compose dependencies have **different releases**.
The version `androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.3.0-beta02` doesn't exist.
You can check it in the [google maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.compose.compiler:compiler)

You can in any case use the stable version of the module compiler `1.3.1` and all the other compose dependencies at `1.2.1` or `1.3.0-beta02`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.3.1'         //compiler
        compose_version = '1.3.0-beta02'   //compose dependencies
        compose_material3 = '1.0.0-beta02' //material3 release
    }
    //...
}
```

and then:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
   // beta 1.3.0 releases
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
   //... 

   //material3
   implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$compose_material3"
}
```

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) the compiler 1.3.x requires kotlin 1.7.10:

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-beta02. Again I got error like this @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: @SasidharanIOS Because material3 1.3.0 doesn't exist. You have to check your dependencies: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

Comment: Working fine ..Thanl you so much @Gabriele Mariotti

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use 2.42 for androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose and getting error. I use 1.0.0 version and it works. Check all your dependencies last versions from Maven Repository.

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/)